# Using std::find() With Reverse Iterators

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, vector, iterator

I'm having some trouble understanding how to use reverse iterators with the `std::find()` function. I believe that if I could see an example that completed the following task, I would be able to understand it perfectly.

So, suppose I have a `std::vector` I want to search through; however, I do not want to search the typical way. I want to find the first occurrence of a value starting at a certain index and heading towards the start of the vector. To illustrate:

```
    3 | 4 | 7| 4| 2| 6| 3|
    ^             ^
    |<------------| 
             start_point
```

Search: find first occurrence, given the above search layout, of 4

Expected Result: index 3

I'm rather sure that one would have to work with reverse iterators in this situation, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using a `std::vector`, or any other container that provides Random Access Iterators, you can advance an iterator just using arithmetic, like you would with a pointer.  Your example vector has 7 elements, and you want to start at index 4, so you could get a normal iterator to that element just with:

```
auto i = v.begin() + 4;
```

For a reverse iterator, you're starting from the back of the vector, not the front, so to get the right offset you have to subtract the desired index+1 from the size, like so:

```
auto i = v.rbegin() + (v.size() - 5);
```

This'll be, in your example, `2`, so the reverse iterator will start pointing to the last element, then move two spaces toward the beginning, reaching your desired start point.

Then, you can use `std::find` in the normal way:

```
auto found = std::find(v.rbegin() + (v.size() - 5), v.rend(), 4);
if(found == v.rend()) {
    std::cout << "No element found." << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "Index " << (v.rend() - found) << std::endl;
}
```

Remember that, when testing the result of `std::find` to see if it found anything, you need to use `rend()`, not `end()`.  When you compare reverse iterators to normal iterators, you're comparing the actual positions, not the offsets from the start, so `v.rend() != v.end()`.

If you don't have Random Access Iterators (for example, in a `std::list`) you can't use pointer-style arithmetic, so you can instead use `std::advance` to advance iterators to a specific position and `std::distance` to get the distance between two iterators.

Comment: (v.rend() - found) returns an index that is one too large, e.g. in this case 4 instead of the expected index 3.

Answer (score 7):

First you set the start position:

```
auto it = v.rbegin() + 2;  // two from the end
```

Then search:

```
auto kt = std::find(it, v.rend(), 4);
```

If `kt == v.rend()`, no element is found; otherwise we can compute the index from the front with a simple distance computation:

```
if (kt == v.rend()) {
  std::cerr << "Element 4 not found.\n";
  std::abort();
} else {
  auto n = std::distance(kt, v.rend()) - 1;
  std::cout << "Element 4 found at position v[" << n << "].\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try something like the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 3, 4, 7, 4, 2, 6, 3 };
    std::vector<int>::size_type pos = 4;

    auto it = std::find(std::next(v.rbegin(), v.size() - pos), v.rend(), 4);

    if (it != v.rend())
    {
        std::cout << std::distance(v.begin(), it.base() - 1) << std::endl;
    }

}
```